# How can i check disk for defects without boot USB?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb

From menu boot will give you options .One of the options are `check disk for defects`. How can i `check disk for defects` without boot USB.
Are there another ways to do it via `Terminal` or `Software`.
If there are another ways :

1. How can i do it without original .iso?
2. How can i do it with original .iso

Comment: dude, if your install gets stuck where it does, it might be because of ram, have you tried using the mini.iso https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: it downloads in like 10 seconds and is an install only image so it doesn't waste ram for a live session

Comment: The menu boot will give you options. One of the options are check dis for defects. How can i do it without boot?

Comment: sorry, I do not know the answer to your question but I was trying to provide an option that bypasses your original problem with the installation:)

Comment: Oh i just want to check my LiveUSB is good or bad. because i want to downloand and make boot liveUSB from somewhere.

Comment: Install `smartmontools` and run `sudo smartctl -x /dev/sda` . Post output to `paste.ubuntu.com` and link here. Smartctl is a starting point whenever checking health of a disk

Comment: @Fabby this one is  probably in your department

Comment: @Serg sr for late response. [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13486252/)